# What does "si vienen palos" mean?

Tags: traducción

> y es por eso que **si vienen palos**,
>
> yo seré el primero en dar

This is from the lyrics of [a song](http://www.jamendo.com/en/track/404313/recuerdos-de-ceniza). I do understand the meaning of the words but a literal translation doesn't make any sense ("... if sticks come ..."). Is this a metaphor or a figure of speech?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is kind of an expression. It could be roughly translated to "if there is going to be fighting, I will be the first to hit".

There is an expresion *Te voy a moler a palos* that will translate to something like "I will grind you to pieces".

*Palo* it is literally a stick. In that sense the full sentence would be "If people are coming with sticks to hit me, I would be the first to hit", but it does not have to be literally sticks, just an aggression either figurative or literal.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that it might have something to do with fighting but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Is this a common phrase?

Comment: I believe the phrase _"Vienen palos"_ or sometimes _"Pintan Bastos"_ refers to some games played with a Spanish card deck [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baraja_%28playing_cards%29] in which one of the suits is _Palos_ or _Bastos_ (clubs). And that is indeed used to mean it's time for a fight, either literal of figurative.